# How can I create a report button in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to rails and I'm hoping someone can give me an advice. I have an app that shows a list of places to the users and I was hoping to be able to insert a report button (like "this place is permanently closed" or something like that) that when pressed, I would receive an e-mail or something else telling me that the user reported that place. I have no idea how can I achieve that.
I hope I could make myself clear. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

### Model

```
# rails g model report place:belongs_to reason:text
class Report < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :place
end
```

```
class Place < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :reports
end
```

### View

```
# app/views/places/form.html.erb
<%= form_for([place, report]) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :reason %>
    <%= f.text_input :reason %>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit "Report" %>
<% end %>
```

```
# app/views/reports/new.html.erb
<%= render partial: 'form', locals: { place: @place, report: @report } %>
```

```
# app/views/places/show.html.erb
# ...
<%= render partial: 'form', locals: { place: @place, report: @report || Report.new } %>
```

### Controller

```
# config/routes.rb
resources :places do
  resources :reports, only: :create
end
```

```
class ReportsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_place, only: [:create]

  # POST /places/:place_id/reports
  def create
    @report = @place.reports.new(report_params)
    if @report.save
      redirect_to @place, flash: "Report created"
      # @todo send email
      # @see https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html 
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  private

  def set_place
    @place = Place.find(params[:place_id])
  end

  def report_params
    params.require(:report)
          .permit(:reason)
  end
end
```